# XML Reader doesn't work

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a code and it gives me error: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined

```
var mystore = new Ext.data.Store({
    url: 'http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2121267&u=c.xml',
    // specify a XmlReader  
    reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({ 
    record: 'channel', 
    fields:[
            { name: 'title', type: 'string', mapping:'title'}
        ] 
    })
});
mystore.load();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set a proxy, I should look like this:

```
var mystore = new Ext.data.Store({
    fields: [{
        name: 'title',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'title'
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2121267&u=c.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'channel'
        }
    }
});

mystore.load();
```

But I suppose you'll have a cross domain problem, so use the JSON-P api, and set a JSON-P proxy on your store.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, now I have: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2121267&u=c&_dc=1366539116942&page=1&start=0&limit=25. Origin http://localhost:1715 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. ((